# inverting positive CGFloat to negative value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

This might be a very dumb question, but if I have a CGFloat with value of 44.0, how do I make it to -44.0? I tried doing -myFloat and 0 - myFloat but it gives me 0. Why is this? Also I don't want a multiply by -1 answer

Comment: I think the reason it's resetting itself to 0, is that you are trying to assign it to a value that includes itself in the calulation in one go.  Divide it into two operations and try to see if it works.  Otherwise, these are just my mad ramblings, see @No More Wishes post for the answer.

Comment: Why don't you want a "multiply by -1 answer"? Is this a real question?

Comment: Both `-myFloat` and `0 - myFloat` are valid ways of negating a `CGFloat`.  If you're having trouble, **show us your code** instead of giving a vague description of it.

Answer (score 7):

Its very simple dude. Just multiply it with -1.

```
i.e. 44.0 * -1 = -44.0
```

**Update:**

Solution 2 as mentioned by Inafziger

```
yourNo = 0 - yourNo
```

Comment: oh forgot to mention, answer has to be besides multiplying it by -1

Comment: *facepalm* when I just googled how to make a cgfloat negative and got directed to this SO post.

Answer (score 4):

If myFloat is equal to 44.0, then the expression -myFloat will be evaluated as -44.0. You've got a bug somewhere else in your code. Can you post the expression where it "gives you 0"?

Using a clumsy workaround will just make your code harder to read and even worse to debug in the long run. Let's sort out the actual problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so you can't multiply by -1, how about:

```
myFloat = 0 - myFloat;
```

or

```
myFloat = myFloat - 2 * myFloat;
```